# $f(s,t) = (x(s,t),y(s,t),z(s,t))$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

Let $f:I\to \mathbb{R}^2$ given by $f(t) = (x(t),y(t))$ be a differentiable path (of class $C^k$). If $x'(t)\neq 0$ for all $t\in I$, then $f(I)$ is the graph of a differentiable function (of class $C^k$) $\eta :J\to \mathbb{R}$. If $I=\mathbb{R}$ and there exists a constant $c>0$ such that $|x'(t)|\ge c$ for all $t\in \mathbb{R}$, then the function $\eta$ is defined for all $t\in \mathbb{R}$. Let $f:\mathbb{R}^2\to\mathbb{R}^3$ defined by $f(s,t) = (x(s,t),y(s,t),z(s,t))$, where $x(s,t)=e^s\cdot \cos t, y(s,t)=e^s\cdot \sin t$ and $z(s,t) = t$. Show that $f$ is injective, of class $C^{\infty}$, that the jacobian determinant $\frac{\partial x}{\partial s}\frac{\partial y}{\partial t}-\frac{\partial x}{\partial t}\frac{\partial y}{\partial s}$ is different of $0$ in all points $(s,t)\in\mathbb{R}^2$ but its image $f(\mathbb{R}^2)$ is not the graph of a real function of two variables.

First of all, why he calls the jacobian that thing? Isn't the jacobian a matrix?

I'm also concerned about proving that the image is not a graph. For me, I should prove that it's not an injection, but it indeed is

Comment: What is the relation of $f$ at the beginning of the question and $f$ in the second part?

Comment: This question needs a major overhaul.  As Thomas says, there are two $f$'s floating around.  The Jacobian is for the first $f$ but appears in the context of the second one.  I can answer one question though:  The matrix is called "the Jacobian matrix."  The determinant of that matrix is called "the Jacobian."